# How to troubleshoot what process is writing a file

Tags: debian, backup

Some process on my production server, a project I inherited from another web developer, is creating a daily backup of mysql databases and site files. The backups are being stored at `/var/www/html/nightlybackup/` and I would like to move them into `/var/www/backups/` as well as remove a directory that no longer exists and add a new directory.

How can I begin unraveling where this process is defined so that I can make some changes?

I am using Debian 8

Comment: This is a good question for [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) but not a great candidate for Q&A, because it has a very broad scope and "it could be anything". That said, I'll chuck up a throwaway answer :P

Comment: @allquixotic Reformulated as "How do I figure out which process is intermittently writing a file", this would be a good question. And maybe a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## "Things To Try"

### Random sampling / poking around

- Chance of finding the culprit: 50%
- Difficulty: Easy assuming you know what you're looking at

Look in the following places for unusual/unexpected commands:

- `~/bin` of any interactive users
- `ps -ef` (as root) for anything you don't know what it is
- `crontab -e` to edit the `crontab` (cron table) file to determine if it's being run as a cron job every X minutes/hours/days.
- `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` of any users
- `/usr/local/bin` for any files that aren't part of a managed package
- `/opt`
- Instances of scripting languages: bash, java, perl, python, ruby, etc. - that you haven't started, or whose `PPID` (parent PID) in `ps` doesn't lead up the tree to a process you're familiar with and know it isn't doing it
- See if they named the script / executable file the same thing as the directory: `find / -iname \*nightly\*` (could return many false positives, so maybe adding `| less` would be prudent)

There are tons of other ways they could've done it, e.g. from a Java application server, a Perl CGI script, etc., but these are a start.

### Hackish Quick-n-Dirty Semi-Reliable Polling Method

- Chance of finding the culprit: 95%
- Difficulty: Easy (just run this script I hacked together in 5 minutes)

`nohup lsof -r 2 +D /var/www/html/nightlybackup 2>&1 | gzip > nightlybackup-writers.txt.gz &`

In short:

- `nohup` prevents the command line from exiting when you close your terminal or SSH session.
- `lsof` "lists open files", and does so *recursively* on the directory (`+D`), *recurring* indefinitely (`-r`), and refreshes every 2 seconds.
- gzip the results in case you get a lot, to prevent fast filling up your disk.
- You can view the results with the `zless` command.

This command might have a significant performance impact, *especially* on (1) old kernels, or (2) HDD based systems. So run it for a short time and determine how much CPU/disk it's using, and if it's too much, kill the process.

You'll have to leave it running *during* the time that the nightly backup process executes. This is generally the case for any mechanism that could reliably detect this program.

### Ultimate Swiss Army Knives

- Chance of finding the culprit: 99.999999%
- Difficulty: **Extreme** (OS developer level knowledge required, or get lucky and copy a pre-made script that does what you want)

Both [DTrace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTrace) and [SystemTap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SystemTap) are the *ultimate* tools for monitoring the system for a particular pattern of activity. DTrace is arguably better, but many people seem to think it's a [toss-up](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28464191/420156) or that SystemTap is better because it's "native" to Linux (DTrace was added in later after being originally designed for Solaris.)

You could craft a DTrace or SystemTap command / script to capture who's writing to any path in that directory. [Here](https://serverfault.com/a/722832/127863) is an example on Server Fault, along with a useful link to a slew of [DTrace one-liners](http://www.brendangregg.com/DTrace/dtrace_oneliners.txt). Then just have it run in the background (e.g. via `screen` or `nohup`) and wait until the backups hit, and you'll get a process name and PID.

Unless you have a rootkit, and that rootkit is designed to mask its activity from DTrace/SystemTap, and assuming you get the DTrace or SystemTap command right, this **WILL** find what's doing it. But it's also the hardest method.

Comment: You forgot the social solution. Find the web developer, and call him to let him you you have a very special set of skills. That include buying him a drink if he'd tell you what process it is...

Comment: Easier than DTrace/SystemTap would be to simply enable SELinux in permissive mode while 'denying' access to that folder. That should log the access attempts.

Comment: I would add that you need to look at `crontab -e` for all users. I have a one liner for that, but I'm on my phone right now so I can't type it. A shortcut may just be too look through `/var/spool/cron`.

Comment: Yeah, you just upchucked this "throwaway answer".  Right.  It would be scary to see one you actually thought about and worked on.  :-)